# Success function of bootstrap validator is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

My form validation works perfectly but success function is not being triggered at the end. Syntax seems fine. But i am not sure if we can include success function with validator

However, prevent default is doesn't stop it from submitting. any help???

```
$('#editVolForm').bootstrapValidator({

  // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
  feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },

  editPapSub: {
    validators: {
      stringLength: {
        min: 1,
      },
      regexp: {
        regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
        message: "'Submitted Papers' can only consist of numeric characters."
      },
      notEmpty: {
        message: "A valid number of 'Papers Submmited' is required."
      }
    }
  },
  editPapAcc: {
    validators: {
      stringLength: {
        min: 1,
      },
      regexp: {
        regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
        message: "'Accepted Papers' can only consist of numeric characters."
      },
      notEmpty: {
        message: "A valid number of 'Papers Accepted' is required."
      }
    }



  }
}).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: pl share html code